# Is an AK4588VQ decoder able to pass PCM digital audio with its ADC digital interface?

Tags: digital-audio, audio-codec

I want to interface an [AK4588VQ](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/85932/AKM/AK4588VQ.html) with only at maximum 5 wires.  Is it possible? My system uses an STM32F746NG and requires two digital microphones (I2S) and one DAC. I've used this chip because I have it.

I've thought maybe it's possible to use a complex interface like SAI which includes I2S.  This way I could connect my device to an [AK4588VQ](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/85932/AKM/AK4588VQ.html) which handles microphones and a DAC. I know it has to handle DAC but I fear it cannot pass its digital captured data through the DAC connected interface. I've looked at the datasheet but found no clue.

The only hint may be the audio I/F illustrated in chip diagram. We have two I/F diagrams and it seems these are separate and I need at least  two independent I2S to wire this system.

I other word, could it work like this (with dsp digital wire have only one clock shared between mic and speaker data both):
[image: schmatic]

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to achieve with the chip, because it is very unclear. How would you connect the mics and where and what kind of interface your mics have?

Comment: @Justme THX, question updated.